# Setting up Java game pieces

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm just completely at a loss on this one. Here's the instructions and the code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

abstract public class AbstractGamePiece
{

    // These two constants define the Outlaws and Posse teams
    static public final int PLAYER_OUTLAWS = 0;
    static public final int PLAYER_POSSE = 1;

    // These variables hold the piece's column and row index
    protected int myCol;
    protected int myRow;

    // This variable indicates which team the piece belongs to
    protected int myPlayerType;

    // These two strings contain the piece's full name and first letter abbreviation
    private String myAbbreviation;
    private String myName;

    // All derived classes will need to implement this method
    abstract public boolean hasEscaped();

    // Initialize the member variables with the provided data.
    public AbstractGamePiece(String name, String abbreviation, int playerType)
    {

    }

}
```

What I need help with is finishing the code under the public AbstractGamePiece(...) section.

Comment: Please reformat the wall-of-text to something a bit more digestible, and clearly indicate your question.

Comment: If there is something specific about the instructions that are unclear, I'm sure you'll find someone around here glad to help. If the question is "what do I do" it may be hard to help you without defeating the point of your assignment.

Comment: -1 as you're just dumping the provided code and the well formulated, clear, step by step assignment here.

Comment: One step at a time, please.

Comment: fvu, it is pretty well formulated and clear, but as I am fifteen and doing a senior level high school course with no help, I think it's understandable to hit a block every once in a while.

Comment: What is it that you need help with exactly? Reading the assignment steps, adding the methods should be easy enough. If that is too hard... unsure how anyone can help without doing the work for you. Do you use a IDE to code that?

Comment: Jonathan, yeah I have the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to get you going without writing the whole thing for you:

For point 1, the goal is to initialize internal variables (that are already defined in the class) according to the parameters passed to the constructor:

```
public AbstractGamePiece(String name, String abbreviation, int playerType) {
    myName = name;
    // and so on
}
```

Then, a "getter" type function returns a value available in the current object, like this

```
public int getPlayerType() {
    return myPlayerType;
}
```

Setters are the inverse, they set internal variables based on parameters passed:

```
public void setPosition(int col, int row) {
    myRow = row;
    myCol = col;
}
```

And so on.

Then, according to the instructions, you'll have to use this abstract class as the base for several concrete classes:

```
public class Henchman extends AbstractGamePiece {

    // the constructor - not sure what exactly should be passed in here
    // but you get the idea - this constructor doesn't have to have the
    // same "signature" as super's
    public Henchman(String name) {
        super(name, "hm", PLAYER_OUTLAWS);
    }

    // an an implementation of abstract method hasEscaped
    @Override
    public boolean hasEscaped() {
        return false;  // as per the instructions
    }

}
```

A toString method returns a specific description of the current object as a (human-readable) string, and it can e.g be used to print a human-readable list of current pieces to help analyze/debug the game once you start developing the game engine.  As the instructions say, what it does is up to you, make it return all interesting and identifying info.  To get you started, for Henchman:

```
public toString() {
    String.format("Henchman name=%s team=%d escaped=%",myName,myTeam,hasEscaped());
}
```

But there are 1000's of variations on this that would be equally suitable.

This should get you started, do not hesitate to create a new question if you get stuck later on.  Good luck!

Comment: What should I do for this part: This method should form a descriptive string based on the piece’s type, name, and current position (column and row). The exact format of the string is up to you!
public String toString()  I think there is supposed to be an if else statement and returning something, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @TheProfessor I'll edit my answer